# In Jupyter, how to scroll horizontally using the mouse wheel?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In JupyterLab, I can scroll vertically using the mouse wheel. But how to scroll horizontally?

I tried pressing `CTRL`, `SHIFT`, `ALT`, and various combinations thereof, but none seem to work.

Is there a way to scroll horizontally using the mouse wheel combined with a keypress?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to scroll? Text in code editor? A CSV file?

Comment: @krassowski It was a CSV file.

Comment: I think it is not implemented as for today. Please do open an enhancement request on JupyterLab GitHub. What version of JupyterLab do you use? If 2.x there are some alternative CSV viewer/editor extensions that may have this feature.